# Screen goes dark after suspending or locking from Xfce logout menu

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, suspend, xfce

I know that there are multiple others questions about screen not turning on when waking computer from suspend, but I do believe my issue is different from the others.

[image]

If I select *Suspend* from the Xfce logout (rightmost button on the panel) menu my machine suspends just fine, but on waking up again the screen first turns on briefly (showing for only a fraction of a second, first a console with a blinking cursor then then a black screen with my mouse pointer on it) then it goes completely dark (i.e. backlight turns off too) and doesn't turn on again unless I switch to a console (with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>).

After that point everything works normally, and I can go back to the login screen (with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F8</kbd>), type my password and resume using my computer.

This behaviour *only* occur when I suspend using the Xfce logout menu. Suspending using with other commands works just fine. (E.g. running `sudo systemctl suspend` or `echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state` both work fine, even inside a terminal in X.) I have also configured Xfce Power Manager to suspend when I close my laptop lid, and this too works without a hitch.

[image: Xfce Power Manager Settings]

Also, if I boot from a Live USB stick with the Lubuntu 18.04 installer and suspend using the Xfce logout menu there everything works as expected.

Comment: Have a try to look at https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/an3t1p/power_manager_blank_after_option_doesnt_let_me/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was caused by the screen locker/screen saver `light-locker` so I 'solved' the problem by disabling the screen locker.

To disable, click on the Lubuntu menu (in the panel) then 'Preferences > Default applications for LXSession'. Thereafter go to the 'Autostart' tab, and un-check 'Screen Locker'. (Then log out and in again.)

[image]

The reason for me putting 'solved' in quotes is that this renders the 'Lock Screen' option in the Xfce logout menu useless – but now 'Suspend' will work (and 'Hibernate' too, if you have enabled that) without the screen going blank when you resume.